# Prevent angular from handling a url

Tags: angularjs, url, angular-ui-router, carousel

I have an angular web page in which I also have a twitter bootstrap carousel.

The carousel have arrow buttons to jump to the next/previous image with the following url: http://localhost:8080/#myCarousel

Whenever I click on it, it takes me to http://localhost:8080/#/

I tried removing every angular reference and just building an html static version of the page and it works ok, so I guess that the angular router is handling the url with the #myCarousel fragment.

How can I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 1):

On clicking the arrows the url changes in the address bar and the router handles the change which is the required behaviour. Use carousel directive from ui-bootstrap to implement the carousel or you can write ur custom function on click of those links

Answer (score 1):

Angular uses `#` as the prefix for any route handled by it by default.  This allows angular routes to be handled as if they are page anchors, and allows the page to update without a new browser request going to the server.  Unfortunately, JQuery also uses this technique.

To avoid this conflict, you can change the prefix which is used by angular.  From the angular [Documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location):

```
$locationProvider.hashPrefix("!");
```

This will result in Angular links as `/#!` rather than `/#`.  You can also optionally enable HTML5Mode, which uses HTML5 Push State to handle URLs without a hash at all, in browsers that support it.  You should still consider adding a hash prefix as a fallback, for older browsers.